# What is the value of $\int_{-1}^{2} 4 \, x^2 \, (2+x-x^2) \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{2} 4 \, x^2 \, (2+x-x^2) \, dx$$

- When I solved this took the constant out of the integral and then multiplied $x^2$
  by the bracket and evaluated the integral to get:
  $$4 \, \left[ \frac{x^4}{4} +\frac{2x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{5} \right]^2_{-1}=\frac{63}{20}$$
- But when I solve this integral on my calculator on (Casio 991ERX) or Wolfram I get $ \frac{63}{5}$. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know why, but when I plug in the bounds, I indeed get 63/5.

Comment: Did you multiply the four? You got [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x%5E2%28x%2B2-x%5E2%29+from+-1+to+2) probably.

Comment: A computational mistake on your part, I'm guessing. I just put this into a calculator and I got 63/5.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you one of the simplest yet most deadly mistakes.

Comment: Most likely you just forgot to multiply in the $4$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do it step by step:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{2}4x^{2}(x + 2 - x^{2})\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{-1}^{2}(4x^{3} + 8x^{2} - 4x^{4})\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \left(x^{4} + \frac{8x^{3}}{3} - \frac{4x^{5}}{5}\right)\bigg\rvert_{-1}^{+2}\\\\
& = \left(16 + \frac{64}{3} - \frac{128}{5}\right) - \left(1 - \frac{8}{3} + \frac{4}{5}\right)\\\\
& = \frac{176}{15} + \frac{13}{15} = \frac{189}{15} = \frac{63}{5}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be simplifying the integral, like this:

$$\displaystyle \int -4x^{4} + 4x^{3} + 8x^2 \,dx$$
$$-4\int x^4dx + 4\int x^3 dx + 8\int x^2 dx$$

use the power rule, $$\int x^n \,dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

and apply to the problem

$$-4 \times\frac{x^5}{5} + 4\times \frac{x^4}{4} + 8 \times\frac{x^3}{3}$$

Now just plug in the values and you should get 12.6 :)